# How to integrate social signup/signin with Auth0 with AWS Lambda with Python?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, python-social-auth

I have already setup email-password based signup/signin function, at this moment, I'd like to ad social signup/signin function on the project. The project is working on the AWS Lambda Python3.7 runtime.

Answer (score 0):

- I am not sure if i have understood your question completely, Hope this helps.
- You will have to use aws congnito and then add social identiy provider to the user pool [aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-social-idp.html)